# About com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

When I used [`SlidingUpPanelLayout`](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), I have to set two children layout (main and panel). When the second layout (the panel) is opened, I want to close it using a `Button`. But I couldn't find the method.

What is the method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**LAST VERSION AT THE BOTTOM**

If I understand you well, you want to implement a `listener` when the second `view` is opened right?

The way to do that would be like this:

first declare an `SlidingUpPanelLayout`:

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout layout;
```

then, initialize it in `onCreate()`

```
layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
```

After, that if you want, you can set its children clickable by:

```
layout.setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);
```

Now, the important part is this one. Adding the listener to the `layout`

```
 layout.setPanelSlideListener(new PanelSlideListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Anything you put here is going to happen if the view is closed
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Anything you put here is going to happen if the view is open
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I hope this helps! Happy coding!

**EDIT:** If you want to close and/or open the pane, there are two `boolean` methods within the class:

```
layout.collapsePane(true); //to close
layout.expandPane(true); //to open
```

**EDIT. Current Version** [Link to example](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/demo/DemoActivity.java)

```
layout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED); //to close
layout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED); //to open
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please, approve the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Perfect. That is the way :)

Comment: as of version 3.0.0 use layout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState) method

Comment: @Luis : need your help on this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37154986/5209982
Thanks :)

Comment: @VipiNNegi I am sorry. It's been a while, and the library seemed to have changed their methods. So, my answer here is obsolete. If I get some time tonight, I'll try to set up a working example for you. Check out [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/demo/DemoActivity.java) example that Umano has on their github. It starts on line `86`. Maybe, it will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This one is for the latest version of com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library

1. Declare the SlidingUpPanelLayout

   SlidingUpPanelLayout mSlideUpPanel;
2. Initialize it :

   mSlideUpPanel = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingUpPanel);
3. for the listener:

   mSlideUpPanel.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
               @Override
               public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

   ```
           }

           @Override
           public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {

           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With new version use **setFadeOnClickListener**

```
 /**
     * Provides an on click for the portion of the main view that is dimmed. The listener is not
     * triggered if the panel is in a collapsed or a hidden position. If the on click listener is
     * not provided, the clicks on the dimmed area are passed through to the main layout.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setFadeOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        mFadeOnClickListener = listener;
    }
```